# Better to use two many to many tables or one table with three Foreign Key References

Tags: c#, sql, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I'm Creating a WCF Web Service and mapping my domain model using Fluent Nhibernate and I have noticed that the objects can be represented in different ways and so can the data behind it.

Basically I have three tables, one is a Meetings table, one is a MeetingPlaces table, and the other is an Attendee table.  Basically the application will work such that a Meeting is set up, and Attendees will go, but they will also vote for a Location.  So Basically Many Meetings have Many Attendees, and Many Attendees have Many Votes (granted a constraint is put on such that they only have one vote per meeting.  It looks as such.  So to represent this I have the three base tables and a Many To Many (to many? Table)

```
CREATE TABLE Meetings (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndTime DATETIME NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE Attendees (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE MeetingPlaces (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name NOT NULL,
    Address NULL
)

CREATE TABLE MeetingAttendees (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    MeetingId INT NOT NULL, 
    AttendeeId INT NOT NULL, 
    MeetingPlaceId INT NULL, --in case they have no preference

    CONSTRAINT  FK_MeetingAttendees_To_Events FOREIGN KEY (MeetingId) REFERENCES Meetings(Id),
    CONSTRAINT  FK_MeetingAttendees_To_Attendees FOREIGN KEY (AttendeeId) REFERENCES Attendees(Id),
    CONSTRAINT  FK_MeetingAttendees_To_MeetingPlaces FOREIGN KEY (MeetingPlaceId) REFERENCES MeetingPlaces(Id)
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX U_IDX_Meeting_Attendees ON MeetingAttendees(MeetingId, AttendeeId)
GO
```

My question is, is it better to use this structure, or create two separate tables.  One representing The Attendees to a meeting, and the other representing the attendee's vote to meeting attendees as such:

```
CREATE TABLE MeetingAttendees
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    MeetingId INT NOT NULL, 
    AttendeeId INT NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT  FK_MeetingAttendees_To_Events FOREIGN KEY (MeetingId) REFERENCES Meetings(Id),
    CONSTRAINT  FK_MeetingAttendees_To_Attendees FOREIGN KEY (AttendeeId) REFERENCES Attendees(Id),
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX U_IDX_Meeting_Attendees ON MeetingAttendees(MeetingId, AttendeeId)

CREATE TABLE AttendeeVote(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    MeetingAttendeeId INT NOT NULL,
    MeetingPlaceId INT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_AttendeeVote_To_MeetingAttendees FOREIGN KEY (MeetingAttendeeId) REFERENCES MeetingAttendees(Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_AttendeeVote_To_MeetingPlaces FOREIGN KEY (MeetingPlaceId) REFERENCE MeetingPlaces(Id)
)
```

I'm concerned because I'm not sure how Fluent-NHibernate will handle the first solution, and the second, while a bit contrived seems more structurally sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an associative entity between each many-to-many relationship.

If I understand your case correctly:

- Meeting (meeting info)
- Attendee (attendee info)
- MeetingVote (meeting_id, attendee_id, more info)
- MeetingAttendee (meeting_id, attendee_id, more info)

This would be normalized and properly represent the behavior of your application.

Some would argue that if this application is reading 90+% of the time than you should de-normalize, but if you are reading and writing regularly you should have two separate associative entities.

Comment: In the cases you listed the **MeetingVote** and **MeetingAttendee** are the same, not sure what you are seeing **MeetingVote** should be in your example.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. The MeetingVote table would represent when a person voted for a meeting? MeetingAttendee would represent when someone attended a meeting.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the MeetingVote should be Attendee Vote.  It is when an attendee (for a meeting) votes on a place fore where the meeting should take place.  So the meeting, attendee, and place are associated with one another my first solution.

Comment: Aaah ok. The assumption I see with only using one assciative entity is that an attendee must must attend and vote for a place. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, great point, I totally missed that.  I guess an Attendee doesn't have to go to a meeting, they really should be a "Member", and their classification as an attendee is up to the associative table.  
I suppose I can create the first associative table between meeting-Member as MeetingAttendees, then the second will be the between MeetigAttendees and Locations as MeetingVotes.  This way it can be optional for a meeting to attend, and I can restrict a member that does attend to one vote with a unique index.  Does that seem sound?

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely work. If I may, would suggest making the MeetingAttendees an actual entity with a surrogate, one-column key, to make your association to MeetingVotes cleaner. A composite key would work too though if you can't do a surrogate.